# Одна БД sqlite на 2 приложения

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Создаю БД в одном приложении. В другом приложении обращаюсь к уже созданной БД, ничего не выходит. Однако если я обращаюсь к БД в том же приложении, где её создал, то всё нормально. **ВОПРОС**: Как сделать так, чтобы создать БД в одном приложении, а обращаться к этой же БД в другом?

Использую AndroidStudio, sqlite, java;

Comment: Нужно убедиться, что оба приложения обращаются к одному файлу.

Comment: Не хватает подробностей задачи. В данный момент гугл закрывает файловую систему ОС и простым образом вы это просто не реализуете без адовых костылей и рута. Однако, если второе приложение должно только считывать данные, то используйте `ContentProvider`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev В этом и вопрос. Как это сделать?